# Chat command for discordjs bot

Tags: javascript, command, discord

I'm making a bot on discord which I would add more commands in the future, I just
don't understand the use of arguments and how would it work if there is a space like ";say general(the channel) hi guys I'm a text (the text to send)". It will only send "hi" to general and nothing else which is a downside to the chat command.

```js
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});


bot.on("ready", async () => {
 console.log(`Bot is ready! ${bot.user.username}`);


 try {
  let link = await bot.generateInvite("[ADMINISTRATOR]");
  console.log(link);
 } catch(e) {
   console.log(e.stack);
 }
 
 bot.user.setGame('nope nope nope');

});

bot.on("message", async (message) => {
 if (message.author.bot) return;
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
 
 let command = message.content.split(" ")[0];
 command = command.slice(prefix.length);
 
 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
 
 if (command === "ping") {
  message.channel.send(`Pong! Time took: ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp} ms`);
 } else

 if (command === "say") {
  message.delete()
  let thetext = args[2];
  let thechannel = args[1];
  
  bot.channels.find("name",`${thechannel}`).sendMessage(`${thetext}`)
 }

});
```

Comment: You need to get all the strings from index 2 onwards for your text, and join them with a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand you correctly, everything works except the message only includes the first word of said message. This occurs because you're grabbing `args[2]` which only grabs the second argument (or second word). In order to get the entire message, you would do this:`let theText = args.slice(1).join(' ');`.

**Explanation of code snippet**
`slice(1)` what this does is remove the first argument which is the text channel.
`join(' ')` This joins all the arguments that are after the first arg.

In conclusion, if the person ran this command: `say general My message is awesome`. This would be the variables: `theChannel = 'general'` `theMessage = 'My message is awesome'`

Answer (score 0):

U should try this if I think u want to repeat the message from a user.
My bot prefix is `R!`
My command is `echo`
So my message is

```
if(command==='echo'){
let ec = message.content;
let co = ec.replace("R!echo","");
message.channel.send(co);
}
```

Hope this helps you...
If u need help join my server
https://discord.gg/Rf3xPMm